# Why use reset_index(drop=True) when setting the index is much faster?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, series

Why would I use `reset_index(drop=True)`, when the alternative is much faster? I am sure there is something I am missing. (Or my timings are bad somehow...)

```
import pandas as pd

l = pd.Series(range(int(1e7)))

%timeit l.reset_index(drop=True)
# 35.9 ms +- 1.29 ms per loop (mean +- std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit l.index = range(int(1e7))
# 13 us +- 455 ns per loop (mean +- std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Comment: Of the top of my head: 1) You are hard coding the length of the DataFrame (probably negligible) 2) `reset_index(drop=True)` returns a copy (can be an advantage if you are chaining methods).

Comment: Great. Thanks. I guess this q deserves an answer instead of deletion since I am sure sb else will wonder the same thing.

Comment: @user2285236, For (1) using `len(l.index)` instead doesn't add much time, (2) I often hear "chaining methods" as something that is *inherently good* about pandas, but I find it often obfuscates logic.

Comment: @jpp I guess it is considered good because the *hardest* thing in programming is naming things and method chaining helps you with that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The costly operation in reseting the index is not to create the new index (as you showed, that is super fast) but to return a copy of the series. If you compare:

```
%timeit l.reset_index(drop=True)
22.6 ms ± 172 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit l.index = range(int(1e7))
14.7 µs ± 348 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit l.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
13.7 µs ± 121 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

You can see that the inplace operation (where no copy is returned) is more or less equally fast as your methode. However it is [generally discouraged](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16529) to perform inplace operations.